# Microsoft Visio Dynamic Connectors

Tags: dynamic, connection, mouseevent, visio

I'm creating a bunch of flowcharts for data mapping through this database I'm working with, however it's getting quite messy and I was looking for a solution. Right now I have a ton of lines connecting all the variables together, but I was wondering if there is a way to add mouse over events to a text object or something so that when you hover over it, it display a connecting arrow to whatever it is related to; and removing your mouse from the object would make the connector disappear.

Does visio have any sort of support for this type of action in macros or in the ShapeSheet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any mouseover event in Visio, but there is a mouse move event.  So every time the mouse moves you find out if the mouse is over one of your shapes, and if so then draw your arrow, if not, delete any existing arrow(s).

Finding the shapes under the mouse, quickly, may be a challenge.  I don't know of any Visio routine to get the shapes that occupy an x, y point.  You can draw a circle and use the SpatialNeighbors routine to find other shapes at that point.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with anything in Visio other than dragging and dropping the shapes onto flowcharts. Do you have any links or details about how I would get something like that to work (actually automating the drawing and deleting on mouse move). Thanks.